# Jupyter Notebook invalid password

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm experiencing a problem with Jupyter that I don't understand it.
Here are my observations.

- When I reset the config and run `jupyter notebook`, Jupyter seems completely useless, i.e. when I try to create a notebook it gives me a forbidden error and a simillar thing happens for basically any button on the page.
- If I press the Jupyter logo to go to the homepage it asks me for a password or token and then doesn't accept the token calling `jupyter notebook` gives me
- If I set a password using `jupyter notebook password` or using `notebook.auth.passwd` and open the notebook again it doesn't accept the password that I just created

This consistently persisted even after I tried updating and downgrading the version of Jupyter I have installed.

I have also noticed that the console shows `Forbidden` whenever the webpage makes a request

```
[W 20:12:18.096 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/contents (::1) 2.50ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 20:12:18.099 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 20:13:04.159 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/sessions?_=1509999126632 (::1) 2.50ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
[W 20:13:52.770 NotebookApp] 401 POST /login?next=%2Ftree (::1) 17.01ms referer=http://localhost:8888/login?next=%2Ftree
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable password of jupyter.
First you can set token to set password or disable the password with setting the empty string for token.

Create > jupyter_notebook_config.py 
 with the following content:

> c.NotebookApp.token = u''

or you can run just this command:

> echo "c.NotebookApp.token =''" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

Append an option on the command line
Run Jupyter with an option

> $ jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.token=

Comment: My problem had gone away after a while, likely due to some update, so I can't test if your solution would have worked

Comment: I got it , maybe it will be the solution to someone else